# static_assert in not initialized template class with valid specialization

Tags: c++, templates, static-assert

My question is, whether the following code is valid:

```
template<int i> class Class
{
    static_assert(sizeof(i) == 0, "Class instantiated with i != 1");
};

template<> class Class<1> {};
```

This snippet compiles with `g++`. But `clang++` is trapped by the `static_assert`:

```
error: static_assert failed "Class instantiated with non-int type"
```

A template that uses a type instead of an `int` like

```
template<typename T> class Class
{
    static_assert(sizeof(T) == 0, "Class instantiated with non-int type");
};

template<> class Class<int> {};
```

is accepted by both compilers. Exactly the same pattern applies to function templates.

I found [open-std.org::Non-dependent static_assert-declarations](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#1483), but that does not seem to apply, because my `static_assert` is dependent on the template parameter.

You may check the described behavior on [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/g/wBCgA2)

**EDIT**: As Johan Lundberg points out in the comment my question is wrong. Indeed `sizeof(i)` does not depend on the template parameter. Also R.Sahu is completely right: It would make much more sense to assert `i != 1`. For this again both compilers accept the code.

However, still the upper example compiles with `g++`. As [open-std.org::Non-dependent static_assert-declarations](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#1483) applies to that case (I apologize again for the wrong question in this respect): Is `g++` actually wrong in compiling the code without error?

Comment: I don't think you are correct in "because my static_assert is dependent on the template parameter.". sizeof(i) does not depend on the *value* of i.

Comment: Why do you use sizeof in the first example? i is of type int and sizeof(i) is the same as sizeof(int). Perhaps in the assertion you want to use i directly.

Comment: Did you mean to use `static_assert(i != 1, "Class instantiated with i != 1");` by any chance?

Comment: I think that both are incorrect, as no valid instantiation are valid.

Comment: @Jarod42: Are you sure that even the second snipped with `typename T` is incorrect? Because here the `static_assert` *is* dependent on the template parameter (even when it is always false). Why should it be incorrect?

Comment: For the second example: 14.6/8 "If no valid specialization can be generated for a template, and that template is not instantiated, the template is ill-formed, no diagnostic required."

Comment: @aschepler: I know this is opinion based, but what is the correct (not ill-formed) way to implement such scheme (no default but several specializations)? Should one only declare the class without any definition like `template<typename T> class Class;` and offer a definition only for the valid specializations? The compiler would surely complain if no valid specialization is available. Or is there another point to consider?

Comment: Not defining the primary template is the way the Standard goes, for example `std::function<T>`.  You can also define a `template<int N> struct always_false : public std::false_type {};` and do `static_assert(always_false<i>::value, "My error");`

Comment: This discussion led me to file gcc bug 80368 https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80368

Answer (score 1, accepted):

clang++ is right to reject your code, but g++ is not wrong to fail to catch the error; this is a "no diagnostic required" situation.

The Standard strictly defines expressions within a template as "type-dependent" and/or "value-dependent".  Given `template<int i>`, `i` is value-dependent but not type-dependent.

> [14.6.2.2/4]: Expressions of the following forms are never type-dependent (because the type of the expression cannot be dependent):
>
> - ...
> - `sizeof` *unary-expression*
> - ...
>
> [14.6.2.3/2]: Expressions of the following form are value-dependent if the *unary-expression* or *expression* is type-dependent or the *type-id* is dependent:
>
> - `sizeof` *unary-expression*
> - ...

So `sizeof(i)` is not dependent.

Finally, 14.6/8 says:

> If a hypothetical instantiation of a template immediately following its definition would be ill-formed due to a construct that does not depend on a template parameter, the program is ill-formed; no diagnostic is required.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you want to assert that the template has been instanciated with the wrong type, you must be explicit in the static_assert:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T> class Class
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<T, int>::value, "Class instantiated with non-int type");


};
```

Secondly, the following line may not be doing what you think:

```
template<> class Class<int> {};
```

What you're actually doing here is creating a whole new specialisation, which has nothing whatsoever to do with the default template specialisation`Class<T>`.

Deleting the specialisation for `int` and instanciating a non-int class of the default specialisation yields an error in both compilers as it should:

```
int main()
{
    Class<int> ci;
    Class<float> cf;
}
```

example error:

```
<source>: In instantiation of 'class Class<float>':
<source>:14:18:   required from here
<source>:5:5: error: static assertion failed: Class instantiated with non-int type
     static_assert(std::is_same<T, int>::value, "Class instantiated with non-int type");
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I think your idea is somewhat different to mine. I think of a class that has no (useful) default implementation, but offers several (not only one) specializations. By this I can select the appropriate implementation during compilation.The `static_assert` provides only a readable error message.

Comment: @marlam right... but remember that each specialisation that you define represents a whole new class, which does not have the `static_assert` in it. You are defining `Class<int>`, not instantiating it.

Comment: Correct, that is what I meant. It would counteract the idea if the `static_assert` were in every specialization. However, we are now still with the question, why `g++` accepts the first snippet (see the edit in the question).